# Wikidata LabelService does not behave as expected

Tags: sparql, wikidata, blazegraph

The following Wikidata query does not work as I would expect it:

```
# WikiData SPARQL Query
#
# Wolfgang Fahl 2018-01-06
#
# get father of queen victoria
SELECT ?queenVictoria ?queenVictoriaLabel ?fatherProperty ?fatherPropertyLabel ?father ?fatherLabel
WHERE {
#  
# father
# https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P42
# Queen Victoria
# https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q9439
  BIND (wdt:P22 AS ?fatherProperty).
  BIND (wd:Q9439 AS ?queenVictoria).
  ?queenVictoria ?fatherProperty ?father.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

[try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#%23%20WikiData%20SPARQL%20Query%0A%20%20%20%20%23%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20Wolfgang%20Fahl%202018-01-06%0A%20%20%20%20%23%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20get%20father%20of%20queen%20victoria%0A%20%20%20%20SELECT%20%3FqueenVictoria%20%3FqueenVictoriaLabel%20%3FfatherProperty%20%3FfatherPropertyLabel%20%3Ffather%20%3FfatherLabel%0A%20%20%20%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20father%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fwiki%2FProperty%3AP42%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20Queen%20Victoria%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fwiki%2FQ9439%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20BIND%20%28wdt%3AP22%20AS%20%3FfatherProperty%29.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20BIND%20%28wd%3AQ9439%20AS%20%3FqueenVictoria%29.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FqueenVictoria%20%3FfatherProperty%20%3Ffather.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A)

The result is

```
queenVictoria queenVictoriaLabel fatherProperty fatherPropertyLabel                     father.      fatherLabel   
wd:Q9439      Queen Victoria     wdt:P22        http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/P22 wd:Q157009   Prince Edward Augustus, Duke of Kent and Strathearn
```

I was expecting the labels to be Queen Victoria, father and "Prince Edward Augustus".

**Whats wrong with my query? Or is this a bug?**

Comment: As to "Queen Victoria", 9429 != 9439. As to "father", it seems that Wikidata label service supports `wd`-properties only. As to "Prince Edward", look into Wikidata page.

Comment: :D that is **not** Queen Victoria, click https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q9429

Comment: Correct output: `wd:Q9439 Victoria wdt:P22 http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/P22  wd:Q157009 Edward Augustus, Duke of Kent and Strathearn`

Comment: @WolfgangFahl, [try it](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3FqueenLabel%20%3FrealpropertyLabel%20%3FfatherLabel%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Fqueen%29%20%7B%28wd%3AQ9439%29%7D%0A%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Fproperty%29%20%7B%28wdt%3AP22%29%7D%0A%20%20%3Fqueen%20%3Fproperty%20%3Ffather%20.%0A%20%20%3Frealproperty%20wikibase%3AdirectClaim%20%3Fproperty%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22de%22.%20%7D%0A%7D).

Comment: @Stanislav Kralin - thank you - I fixed the typo - please post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why `http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/P22` is returned instead of `father` is that Wikidata truthy [predicates](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format#Predicates) do not have labels (try `DESCRIBE wdt:P22`). Only proper [properties](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format#Properties) have labels (try `DESCRIBE wd:P22`).

Wikidata [label service](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_query_service/User_Manual#Label_service) could wrap this situation, but it [doesn't](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service/queries#Adding_labels_for_properties):

> `SERVICE wikibase:label` only supplies labels for entities in the wd:
>   namepace.

Thus, [try](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3FqueenLabel%20%3FrealpropertyLabel%20%3FfatherLabel%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20(%3Fqueen)%20%7B(wd%3AQ9439)%7D%0A%20%20VALUES%20(%3Fproperty)%20%7B(wdt%3AP22)%7D%0A%20%20%3Fqueen%20%3Fproperty%20%3Ffather%20.%0A%20%20%3Frealproperty%20wikibase%3AdirectClaim%20%3Fproperty%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D) this query:

```sql
SELECT ?queenLabel ?realpropertyLabel ?fatherLabel
WHERE {
  VALUES (?queen) {(wd:Q9439)}
  VALUES (?property) {(wdt:P22)}
  ?queen ?property ?father .
  ?realproperty wikibase:directClaim ?property
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```