# How to get the label of the relationship from WikiData's SPARQL endpoint?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

Most questions in SO asks for the label of a property. I want the label of the relationship. This is my first attempt.

```
SELECT ?h ?hLabel ?kLabel
WHERE
{
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
  wd:Q11462 ?h ?k.  
}
```

Unfortunately, ?hlabel returns the URL of the properties (ie. `http://www.wikidata.org/prop/P190`)

Trying something like this, gives an empty result.

```
SELECT ?h ?z ?kLabel
WHERE
{
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
  wd:Q11462 ?h ?k.  
  ?h rdfs:label ?z
}
```

I'm wondering how I should attempt this.

Comment: well, it's exactly the same as in the answers of those questions - your relation is nothing more than a property, so the answers still hold: `SELECT ?h ?hLabel ?kLabel
WHERE
{
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
  wd:Q11462 ?rel ?k.  
  ?h wikibase:directClaim ?rel .
}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wikidata LabelService does not behave as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48338287/wikidata-labelservice-does-not-behave-as-expected)